# Как программно получить серийный номер винчестера?

Tags: железо, ассемблер, c++

Скажите, пожалуйста, самый простой способ получения серийного номера жесткого диска (заводского), или приведите исходник на с++ или ассемблере.

В общем тут вот написал, выдает ошибку

ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _WinMain@16 в функции ___tmainCRTStartup

Мой код чувствую не правильный, поэтому прошу помочь, исправить ошибки, и объяснить что к чему.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winioctl.h>
#include <tchar.h>
using namespace std;

    _OVERLAPPED ol;
    _STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY spg;
    LPVOID lpInBuffer[1024];
    LPVOID lpOutBuffer[1024];
    LPDWORD lpByteReturned;

int main()
{

    HANDLE hDevice = CreateFile(_T("\\.\DeviceName"),
                                NULL,              
                                FILE_SHARE_READ |
                                FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 
                                NULL,            
                                OPEN_EXISTING,    
                                NULL,              
                                NULL);

    BOOL bResult = DeviceIoControl(hDevice,
                                   IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY,
                                   &spg,
                                   sizeof(spg),
                                   &spg,
                                   sizeof(spg),
                                   lpByteReturned,
                                   &ol);
    if(bResult)
        cout << "Error by DeviceIoControl!!!\n";
    else {
        cout << spg.PropertyId << "\n";
        cout << spg.QueryType << "\n";
        cout << spg.AdditionalParameters[0] << "\n";
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы некорректно настроили среду разработки. Для начала сделайте не "empty project", который предполагает вообще отсутствие каких-либо сгенерированных исходных файлов, а "win32 project", но везде проставьте галки, что нужен проект консольный, можно с MFC. Тогда основная ф-ция программы будет называться .... `_tmain()`. Причем именно с подчеркивания. Вот и в ней пишите все, что Вам нужно. Ес-но, предполагаю, что у Вас MSVC++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поскольку вы предусмотрительно не указали операционку, то я уже додумаю за вас и подскажу, как это делается под Windows.

Берете `DeviceIoControl` и запрашиваете у него `IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY`. Исходник здесь: [diskid32.cpp](http://www.winsim.com/diskid32/diskid32.cpp)

Answer (score 1):

1. Прямой доступ к оборудованию. Делаете доступными порты ввода-вывода (напр., с помощью драйвера userport или giveo, можно драйвер самому написать). Затем работаете с портами контроллера жесткого диска. Надеюсь, [этот материал](http://wiki.osdev.org/ATA_PIO_ModeВ) поможет. Нужно послать команду 0xEC (IDENTIFY DEVICE) и получить паспорт у-ва. Найти в нем серийник не проблема.
2. `IOCTL_SCSI_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT` и аналогичные - можно напрямую в винде посылать команды у-ву. Не смотрите на SCSI в название IOCTL. Этот IOCTL работает и для большинства драйверов IDE-контроллеров. Но может потребуется немного подшаманить.
3. Работа через `IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY`